# C# - Select Diamond Shaped radius based on coordinates within list of custom class

Tags: c#

Gonna be honest, I probably have a bad title there, so allow me to explain. (Title suggestions are welcome!)

First and foremost, I have a 'List' aptly named TileList. Tile is a class that contains a few variables, but the important ones are these two: public int xCoor and public int yCoor.

TileList is automatically filled by an outside function. In this case, it's filled with exactly 100 instances of the Tile class, each with a different set of xCoor and yCoor- with xCoors from 0 to 9 as well as yCoors from 0 to 9, basically simulating a 10x10 grid.

As it's filled by an outside function, it's not always 10x10, it can also be 5x15 or 20x20 and so on.

I have a function that grabs a specific tile, named FindTile- that one works perfectly thus far...

But now I need one that selects a diamond shape from the grid, based on a starting point and a radius. And my own attempt, the FindDiamond function.. is very messy and takes forever to load.. and in fact sometimes doesn't even work.

This is basically what I want to do: [Grid example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOKb0.png)

**Code is down below:**

```
public class Tile
{
    public int xCoor;
    public int yCoor;

    //more variables
}

public class TileFinder
{
    public List<Tile> TileList = new List<Tile>();

    //Give back tiles when generated
    public void SaveGeneratedTiles(List<Tile> Save)
    {
        TileList = Save;
    }

    public Tile FindTile(int tileX, int tileY)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < TileList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (TileList[i].xCoor == tileX && TileList[i].yCoor == tileY)
            {
                return TileList[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<Tile> FindDiamond(int tileX, int tileY, int radius)
    {
        List<Tile> ReturnList = new List<Tile>();

        for (int r = 0; r <= radius; r++)
        {
            int curx = tileX + r;
            int cury = tileY;

            if (curx == tileX) { FindTile(curx, cury); }
            else
            {
                while (curx != -r)
                {
                    curx--;
                    cury--;
                    ReturnList.Add(FindTile(curx, cury));
                }
                while (cury != -r)
                {
                    curx++;
                    cury--;
                    ReturnList.Add(FindTile(curx, cury));
                }
                while (curx != r)
                {
                    curx++;
                    cury++;
                    ReturnList.Add(FindTile(curx, cury));
                }
                while (curx != -r)
                {
                    curx--;
                    cury++;
                    ReturnList.Add(FindTile(curx, cury));
                }
            }
        }
        return ReturnList;
    }
}
```

Frankly, I'm looking for a better way to make this work, that does end in a returned List at the end.. Other parts of my code function off of this, which in fact may also not be the best way, but I'm still blundering my way through this. :)

*TL;DR I'm trying to emulate something like Advance Wars, and I need the diamond shape to select ranges for fog of war vision, indirect attacks, etc.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, to represent a grid, a 2d array would be a much better choice than a list. A list would work as well but is redundant.
If you know the grid to only contain 10x10 tiles, and you can guarantee their order, finding a specific tile by x and y coordinates should be an o(1) operation, not an o(n) linear search like you currently have in `FindTile`. Also in that function, why are you starting from index `1` and not `0`?

To create a diamond pattern should be very straightforward.

Start with the row (`Y` coordinate) of the starting point. From there go `radius` steps backward on the `X` and `radius` steps forward on the `X`. For `radius` rows below and above the starting point, do the same thing, but for each of those rows, decrease `radius` by 1.

Comment: Sorry- the grid is filled automatically by an outside function. I realize now I should've added that to the question, so I've edited it in.. Not sure what you mean with 0(1) operation vs 0(n) linear search..?

..also, glad you caught that mistake there with the index 1, that should've indeed been 0.. Thanks. Anyway, I'll try this, this sounds like a good idea actually.. Do remember that I also want the INSIDE of the diamond, not just the outmost.. but I think I can just loop this again with a smaller radius.

Comment: Ticking this as accepted answer because.. well, a 2d array is indeed a better choice, and I've already.. halved my code.. since changing to a 2d array.. Oops! ^^; Thank you, Rotem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Haven't tested it.

```
public List<Tile> FindDiamond(int tileX, int tileY, int radius)
{
    List<Tile> ReturnList = new List<Tile>();

    for (int x = 0; x < radius; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < radius-x; y++)
        {
            ReturnList.Add(FindTile(tileX + x, tileY + y));
            ReturnList.Add(FindTile(tileX + x, tileY - y));
            ReturnList.Add(FindTile(tileX - x, tileY + y));
            ReturnList.Add(FindTile(tileX - x, tileY - y));
        }
    }
    return ReturnList;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, kinda looks like it'll add the same tiles a few times, and that's something I'd like to avoid.. I'll test it out regardless. :)

Comment: You should refine it to be a grid (Tile[x][y]) as Rotem suggested

Comment: Or if you want to keep the list you could have a method adding to the list only if the item is not already in the list

Comment: I think I have a lot to reconsider. Thanks for the assistance, regardless. :)

Answer (score 0):

The "diamond" can be represented as a circle with distances measured using [Manhattan Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).

Manhattan Distance is measured by the sum of absolute differences of the X and Y coordinates of the points in question.

```
static int ManhattanDistance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    return Math.Abs(x1 - x2) + Math.Abs(y1 - y2)
}
```

This simplifies your `FindDiamond` method to a single line (if using LINQ).

```
List<Tile> FindDiamond(int centerX, int centerY, int radius) {
    return TileList.Where(tile => ManhattanDistance(tile.xCoor, tile.yCoor, tileX, tileY) <= radius).ToList();
}
```

`FindTile` can also be simplified to a one-liner using LINQ:

```
Tile FindTile(int tileX, int tileY) {
    return TileList.FirstOrDefault(tile => tile.xCoor == tileX && tile.yCoor =  tileY);
}
```

If, however you *cannot use LINQ* for some reason, just loop through `TileList` in `FindDiamond` and return all the `Tile` satisfying the clause inside `Where`.

---

I suggest that you improve your design for efficiency though, like @Rotem says. It'll make your code more efficient and quick. `FindTile` is a method I can imagine being called hundreds of times each frame, so it's best to make the code as efficient as possible. Even with variable width and height the method stated by @Rotem will work.

I also recommend that you create your own `Point` structure for easy storage and using `blah.X` and `blah.Y` instead of using `blahX` and `blahY` everywhere. It can also include useful helpers like `ManhattanDistance` and so on.

A sample `Point` structure:

```
struct Point {
    public int X, Y;

    public int ManhattanDistance(Point other) {
        return Point.ManhattanDistance(this, other);
    }

    public static int ManhattanDistance(Point a, Point b) {
        return Math.Abs(a.X- b.X) + Math.Abs(a.Y - b.Y)
    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason why I'm not using LINQ is because I have no idea how it works (or even what it is, tbh). If it helps improve my code, then I'd gladly pick it up.. Question though, does this also get the INSIDE of the diamond? I need every tile within the diamond, not just the outermost tiles. :)

Comment: @Speedy It will get all the tiles *inside* and *on* the radius. Change the `<= radius` to `< radius` will get all tiles except the outermost. Changing it to `== radius` will retrieve only the outermost. Yes, do start learning to use LINQ. It's a great way to get rid of trivial loops in code and makes code more readable. The above code is an example :)

Comment: Well, I definitely have to consider LINQ then.. Thank you for the assistance. :)